# Finish activity on Android back button press, even when soft keyboard is open

Tags: android, back

In my activity, the soft keyboard should more or less always be open. So when a user presses the back button, the activity should finish like normally. However, the default Android behavior is to close the keyboard instead when it is open. This makes the user have to click twice to exit the activity. How can I override this behavior so that the activity always finishes when the back button is pressed, even when the soft keyboard is open? Is there some simple way to do this?

I'm sure this is a common problem, but I did not find this direct question.

Comment: You need to close soft keyboard before closing the Activity.

Comment: @KeLiuyue: I'm sure there exists some way for me to make the user close the soft keyboard and the activity on the same back button press.

Comment: I try some waty to solve it.But it depends on many factors.

Answer (score 1):

I have same situation.I tried so many ways finally i got solution. Here i will share with you. I have solved this using CustomEditText.

**CustomEditText.Java**

```
public class CustomEditText extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText {


    public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    OnKeyPreImeListener onKeyPreImeListener;

    public void setOnKeyPreImeListener(OnKeyPreImeListener onKeyPreImeListener) {
        this.onKeyPreImeListener = onKeyPreImeListener;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            if(onKeyPreImeListener != null)
                onKeyPreImeListener.onBackPressed();
            return false;
        }
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }

    public interface OnKeyPreImeListener {
        void onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.Java**

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity{

       private CustomEditText editSearchMenu;
       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         editSearchMenu = 
         (CustomEditText)findViewById(R.id.editSearchMenu);

         //Initialise  interface
         CustomEditText.OnKeyPreImeListener onKeyPreImeListener=new CustomEditText.OnKeyPreImeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBackPressed() {
                ((MainActivity)getActivity()).finish();
            }
        };

        editSearchMenu.setOnKeyPreImeListener(onKeyPreImeListener);

       }

}
```

**xml file**

```
<com.app.helper.CustomEditText
                    android:id="@+id/editSearchMenu"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/diam5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/custom_rounded_edittext"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ico_search"
                    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/diam20dp"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ico_search"
                    android:hint="@string/M_SEARCH_HINT"
                    android:padding="@dimen/diam10dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/diam16sp" />
```

Hope this will help you...this works in every devices i have tested my self...other solutions are creating problems in some devices..there will be some other solution also...if you get something let me know...

Answer (score 1):

You should implement `TextWatcher`.

**Here is the the code of you requirement.**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TextWatcher{

    EditText editTextt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        editTextt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextt);
        editTextt.addTextChangedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if(before == count + 1)
        {
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this method to hide the keyboard

```
//hides keyoard
    private void hideSoftKeyboard(View v) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
mEditText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            finish();
            return false;
        }
});
```

You can hide Keyboard and finish Activity.

If you use Dialog,you can do like this.

```
 mDialog.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                if (isShowDialog) {
                    isShowDialog = false;
                    mDialog.dismiss();
                    context.finish();
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
});
```

**Note:** It also can use in Dialog.Dismiss Dialog and do something.And you can use `v`、 `keyCode`、 `event`.And it can be used by most View.